# How is the imperfect of 'acabar de [+ infinitive] translated to English?

Tags: traducción, verbos, tiempos-verbales

Does ***yo acababa de cenar*** translate to:

> I had just finished eating dinner

or

> I was just finishing eating dinner

Comment: The former. The latter would be translated as "Estaba terminando de cenar" ("acabando" is most unusual).

Comment: @Gustavson, feel free to post your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Yo acababa de cenar* refers to the moment right after finishing your dinner. In English, the form used for that is the past perfect:

> I had just finished my dinner

Let's try with a complete sentence:

> Yo acababa de cenar cuando llamaron a la puerta

In English you convey the same meaning this way:

> I had just finished my dinner when the door bell rang.

Comment: This is nitpicking, but note the OP didn't specify any context. *Todos los días mientras yo acababa de cenar...* would use the present continuous in English translation.

Comment: @pablodf76 It's taken me a bit to understand you, but now I get it. Yes, *acabar* can be used here with its intrinsic meaning (a synonym of *terminar*) and the English equivalent would use the continuous form (past continuous, in this case). But, based on the comments for the question, I don't think it is the case.

Comment: I just thought this over and I think this is not correct in any case. The imperfect *acababa* must refer to an ongoing action ("I was finishing my dinner"). That's how I'd perceive it, anyway. If my dinner had already been finished when the bell rang I'd say *Yo había acabado* etc.